# Indicate target words in Qualtrics "Highlight" item type

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I want to create a survey item of the `Highlight` question type in which only a few words in the sentence will require a response. For example, in the sentence...

```
Once upon a time there was a young foo who barred / bart his way out of many pickles.
```

...I only want to receive responses for `barred` and `bart`. Specifically, I want respondents to indicate which of the words is most correct, and whether the remaining word is possible or impossible. My problem is that the built-in interface does not indicate which words can be clicked (unless you mouse-over, in which case the background-color becomes gray). This means that my respondents will have to work to find which words require a response.

I want to use javascript to automatically change the background color of the `HLTextWord` elements without any user interaction.  I tried the following, which had the desired effect, but with one bug.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('HLTextWord');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = '#e6ffff';
    }
});
```

This code works initially, but if I click on anything other than an `HLTextWord` element, or the color selection window, then the highlighting is lost. What do I need to do to make the `#e6ffff` highlighting persist until the user selects a new color for that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using JavaScript, under Look & Feel/Advanced/Add Custom CSS, add this:

```
span.HLTextWord {
    background-color:#e6ffff;
}
```

BTW, in case it's important, we recently used the Highlight question in a survey and found out that it doesn't work for people using Android/Chrome v44 (Basically, any recent Samsung Android device where the user hasn't upgraded their browser).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

A lot of times, elements which change color on mouseover, mouseout and click have css classes that are  applied with each of these event.

These elements usually also have a class that remains, irrespective of user interaction with the element.

Since I don't have access to the code, I would recommend that you find this class and add your own css class to it. Preferably with a background color in the rgba format so that you can make it transparent. This will ensure that the existing user experience does not change (too much) but you have also made it easier for them to spot the words.

You can use the developer tools available in firefox or google chrome to pin point the element. These two browsers are the ones I use. So your code would look something like the following:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].className +=" newClass";
    } 
});
```

All you have to do is find the right class to replace 'someClass' and create a new class to replace 'newClass'.

Here is some help for creating the css class - [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)
You can right click on the element that you want to add the class to and click on "inspect element". This will show you all the details that you need to find the existing class name that element. For more help on the developer tools try [this](https://www.browserstack.com/developer-tools) link.

Hope that give you a good start.

It helps to break your question down into smaller parts and search on the forum for answers on how to solve those parts or ask a question when nothing helps.

Thanks

Paras